# Unable to get linkden access token in Android (access toke is not set)

Tags: android

Unable to get access token, is given an exception "access token is not set"

On onAuthSuccess, it return me response `{"expiresOn": 0}`

It was working fine 1 month ago, suddenly it stops to work in all Android apps

```
final LISessionManager sessionManager = LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        sessionManager.init(MainActivityVC.this, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthSuccess() {
                Log.e("Access Token", "== "+sessionManager.getSession().getAccessToken());
                //output -> Access Token = {"expiresOn": 0}

                Log.e("is Token Valid", "== "+sessionManager.getSession().isValid());
                //output -> is Token Valid = false
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                // Handle authentication errors
            }
        }, true);


private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
}
```